# QTableWidgetItem editor background color

Tags: qt, qtablewidgetitem, qcolor

How can I set QTableWidgetItem editor background color?

I set item with not white background

```
setItem(row, column, itm);
```

While I am editing text of this item background is white. I need to make its background color as when it is not in editing state.

Comment: Which kind of Model? Which kind of view? Is there a reason why you want to change background color by delegate instead of using the model?

Comment: What does mean which kind of model and kind of view?

Comment: @Ufx he means, give us more informations about your code ;)

Comment: the view still draws the item even if it has an editor open, afaik. so the editor should have a valid background brush in its palette or its style itself.

Comment: Do you want to change the bg color of the widget itself or do you want to change the bg color of the cell the widget is embedded in?